# Compare two strings to build a select option list

Tags: apex

I am attempting to build a select option list out of two different strings which refer to two separate multi-value fields. Here is the (non-functioning) code which I have right now.

I was able to use this type of method when building a list compared to a string :

```
account a =[select name , (select name from Subsidiaries_and_Brands__r) from account where id =:accountid];
                for(SubsidiariesAndBrands__c s : a.Subsidiaries_and_Brands__r)
                    {
                        //check that selected items dont already contain the keys
                        if(!selectedItems.contains(s.name))
                        options.add(new SelectOption(s.name,s.name));
```

...but now I'm trying to compare two strings and then build a list from that and I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's where I am now :

```
if(selectedMulPickKeyTech==null)
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('',''));
            return options;
        }
        else
        {
            picklistlines = selectedMulPickKeyTech.split('\n');
            for (Integer i=0;i<picklistlines.size();i++)
            {
                String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
                inputvalues=picklistlines[i].split(',');
                for(Integer j=0;j<inputvalues.size();j++)
                {
                  **if(!selectedItems.contains(inputvalue))
                  options.add(new SelectOption(inputvalues[j],inputvalues[j] ));**
                }
            }

        return options;
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much for any help you can give.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You code looks correct though it would be easier if you used interables.

Comment: Lacey - I was unable to figure out how to properly compare the two lists I had already made. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a problem with your code as such, but could it just be case sensitivity? Maybe try something like this (I'm using string iterators as it's a bit easier to read):

```
if(selectedMulPickKeyTech==null)
{
    options.add(new SelectOption('',''));
    return options;
}
else
{
    for (String pickListLine : selectedMulPickKeyTech.split('\n'))
    {
        for(String inputValue : pickListLine.split(','))
        {
            if(!selectedItems.contains(inputValue.toLower()))
                options.add(new SelectOption(inputValue, inputValue));
        }
    }

    return options;
}
```

Of course you'll need to make sure `selectedItems` is also populated with lowercase strings to make the comparison work.

On a side note, where you do this:

```
String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
inputvalues=picklistlines[i].split(',');
```

You're creating a new array and assigning it to the variable `inputvalues`, then replacing it with a different array, it'd be more efficient to just do this:

```
String[] inputvalues = picklistlines[i].split(',');
```